# how does one not get lost in the details?

Tags: halacha, minhag, hashkafah-philosophy, theology, mitzvah

Halachah is very detail oriented and of course all of these details are important but sometimes it seems easy  from time to time to get so focused on the specifics of the right way of how to so something and not who the mitzvahs are from... Is there any advice as to how to not lose focus of the big picture?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31831/759

Comment: See [here](http://www.kolhalashon.com/New/Shiurim.aspx?Lang=English&Path=English|EMusar|R7529&English=True&Order=New2Old&InCall=True), shiur #7

Answer (score 2):

Tanya, [Chapter 41](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/tanya/1/41.htm):

> אך אמנם אמרו רז"ל לעולם אל יוציא אדם עצמו מן הכלל לכן יתכוין ליחד ולדבקה בו ית' מקור נפשו האלהית ומקור נפשות כל ישראל שהוא רוח פיו ית' הנק' בשם שכינה על שם ששוכנת ומתלבשת תוך כל עלמין להחיותן ולקיימן והיא היא המשפעת בו כח הדבור הזה שמדבר בדברי תורה או כח המעשה הזה לעשות מצוה זו
>
> ...
>
> וכן בהכנה זו יתחיל ללמוד שיעור קבוע מיד אחר התפלה וכן באמצע היום קודם שיתחיל ללמוד צריכה הכנה זו לפחות כנודע שעיקר ההכנה לשמה לעכב הוא בתחל' הלימוד בבינונים וכמו בגט וס"ת שצריכים לשמה לעכב ודיו שיאמר בתחלת הכתיבה הריני כותב לשם קדושת ס"ת או לשמו ולשמה כו' וכשלומד שעות הרבה רצופות יש לו להתבונן בהכנה זו הנ"ל בכל שעה ושעה עכ"פ
>
> However the Sages said "A person should never take himself out of the Klal, therefore intend to unify with and attach to G-d the source of his G-dly soul and the source of all Jewish souls ... which gives him the ability to speak in words of Torah and to do Mitzvos ...
>
> Similarly with this preparation he should begin to learn a fixed amount immediately after prayer, and also in the middle of the day before he begins to learn it requires this preparation at least. As is known that the main preparation of intention which is minimally sufficient which is required is at the beginning of learning for the average person, like with a Get and Sefer Torah that require minimially sufficient intention it is enough to say at the beginning of the writing that "I am writing for the sake of the holiness of the Sefer Torah" or "For him and for her" etc. And when he learns several hours in a row, he should meditate with this preparation at least every single hour.