# Why can't I just do Judaism in my own way?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

With society changing and its people changing with it, why is Judaism not adapting accordingly? Why can't I pick from the different Jewish cultures available which I connect? For example Persian, Moroccan, Egyptian or Polish Jewry? Why can't one make a mismatch in their practice of (Orthodox) Judaism, as long as everything comes from a reliable source or another?

Essentially, why can't I create a practice of (Orthodox) Judaism that really connects to me as a Canadian, as opposed to my great-great-grandparents from Poland?

**Note:** I understand I'm coming from an emotional perspective, so it would be more helpful if I got answer from a Hashkafic perspective as opposed to a rigid law.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking whether you can pick and choose traditions to follow? Are you asking whether you can expound halacha as you want and interpret the Torah in your own way? Are you asking why tradition is so important? Please [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/84541/edit) your question to clarify. These are all important questions, but we need to know which one you're asking so that we can answer appropriately. Welcome to Mi Yodeya - hope to see you around!

Comment: Might be a duplicate of the following question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31831/all-the-many-many-details

Comment: Who says you can't do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All the many, many details](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31831/all-the-many-many-details)

Comment: I think you should be content with your Polish roots. Be happy you can even determine your family's minhag at all. Some people's past (including mine) are a little more "murky." :)

Comment: How is this a dupe? That's asking why we have so many details - this one seems to be asking why we can't pick which opinion of those details to follow. But as the OP hasn't clarified and this is up in the queue anyway, my vote is to close as "unclear."

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't one make a mismatch in their practice of (Orthodox) Judaism, as long as everything comes from a reliable source or another?

One very good reason is because you could end up doing contradictory things.

It's okay to pasken a certain way where there is a machlokes, but if you mix and match you could easily end up doing things that are mutually exclusive. This may not always be immediately obvious either - take for example laws derived from ways of interpreting the Torah; they could be entirely unrelated except for the fact they depend on ribbui and meiut vs klal uPrat.

**Edit**

I know this doesn't directly address the 'Hashkafic' point of view, but I think that 'transgressing the Torah' is also hashkaficly frowned upon.